# SQL: Using the LEAD function By Group

Tags: sql, r

I have the following R code that simulates random data for different students flipping coins  counting the number of combinations obtained for all students and calculates conditional probabilities (third result given first two results):

```
    library(dplyr)

    library(tidyverse)
    

   ids = 1:100
student_id = sample(ids, 1000, replace = TRUE)
coin_result = sample(c("H", "T"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
my_data = data.frame(student_id, coin_result)

my_data =  my_data[order(my_data$student_id),]

my_data = my_data %>%
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result), lead(coin_result, 2)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  count(Sequence)

final = my_data %>%
    mutate(two_seq = substr(Sequence, 1, 2)) %>%
    group_by(two_seq) %>%
    mutate(third = substr(Sequence, 3, 3)) %>%
    group_by(two_seq, third) %>%
    summarize(sums = sum(n)) %>%
    mutate(prob = sums / sum(sums))


 # FINAL RESULT (Note: I think this is correct because the pairs of conditional probabilities add to 1)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   two_seq [4]
  two_seq third  sums  prob
  <chr>   <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 HH      H       112 0.514
2 HH      T       106 0.486
3 HT      H       108 0.537
4 HT      T        93 0.463
5 TH      H        97 0.5  
6 TH      T        97 0.5  
7 TT      H        93 0.497
8 TT      T        94 0.503
```

**My Question:** I am trying to convert the above code R into (Netezza) SQL.

I did some research and found out about a LEAD() function that might be able to accomplish this.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT Sequence, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM (
      SELECT
        STUDENT_ID,
        coin_result ||
          LEAD(coin_result, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID ORDER BY STUDENT_ID) ||
          LEAD(coin_result, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID ORDER BY STUDENT_ID) ||
          LEAD(coin_result, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID ORDER BY STUDENT_ID) AS Sequence
      FROM my_data
    ) subquery
    WHERE Sequence NOT LIKE '%NULL%'
    GROUP BY Sequence;
```

**I am not sure if I am doing this correctly - and I am not sure how to add the column of conditional probabilities**

Can someone please show me how to continue?

Thanks!

Comment: Some issues: (1) random data without a seed, we cannot reproduce your table, minor; (2) your dplyr code looks at `lead(.,2)` but your SQL goes up to `lead(.,3)`, inconsistent; (3) `not like '%NULL%'` seems really odd to me, when do you expect the literal "NULL" to be inserted into your coin-flipping? Perhaps `Sequence not null and Sequence <> ''`?  (4) `sum(sums)` is still within the grouping, do you mean to `ungroup()` before calculating the proper proportion? (Perhaps it is auto-dropping the groups for you? It doesn't for me in `dplyr-1.0.10`.)

Comment: @r2evans good observation about the groups. Newer versions of `dplyr` also do not automatically drop groups - OP’s output is still grouped at the end

Answer (score 1):

The amazing dbplyr package has a `show_query` function which shows the dbplyr's SQL translation dplyr code. I did an example using SQLite, so you may need to make some changes depending Netezza's variant of SQL. I changed the first `summarise` to `mutate` to make it work, but the result is the same.

```
library(tidyverse)

ids = 1:100
student_id = sample(ids, 1000, replace = TRUE)
coin_result = sample(c("H", "T"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
my_data = data.frame(student_id, coin_result)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, my_data)

tbl(con, "my_data") %>% 
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  mutate(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result), lead(coin_result, 2))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  count(Sequence) %>% 
  mutate(two_seq = substr(Sequence, 1, 2)) %>%
  group_by(two_seq) %>%
  mutate(third = substr(Sequence, 3, 3)) %>%
  group_by(two_seq, third) %>%
  summarize(sums = sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(prob = sums / sum(sums)) %>% 
  show_query()
```

Output:

```
<SQL>
SELECT `two_seq`, `third`, `sums`, `sums` / SUM(`sums`) OVER (PARTITION BY `two_seq`) AS `prob`
FROM (SELECT `two_seq`, `third`, SUM(`n`) AS `sums`
FROM (SELECT `Sequence`, `n`, `two_seq`, SUBSTR(`Sequence`, 3, 1) AS `third`
FROM (SELECT `Sequence`, `n`, SUBSTR(`Sequence`, 1, 2) AS `two_seq`
FROM (SELECT `Sequence`, COUNT(*) AS `n`
FROM (SELECT `student_id`, `coin_result`, CONCAT_WS('', `coin_result`, LEAD(`coin_result`, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY `student_id`), LEAD(`coin_result`, 2.0, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY `student_id`)) AS `Sequence`
FROM `my_data`)
WHERE (NOT(((`Sequence`) IS NULL)))
GROUP BY `Sequence`)))
GROUP BY `two_seq`, `third`)
```